# I can't get my Projection Matrix to have a proper perspective for a Rotation animation

Tags: uwp, windows-composition-api, xaml-composition

I`m trying to replicate a plane projection rotation in UWP using the composition api. But I'm having trouble with a projection matrix in my composition code. Here`s what I have:

```
private void Perspective(FrameworkElement element, double duration, float rotationDepth = 750f)
{
    var parent = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element.Parent as FrameworkElement);

    var width = (float)element.ActualWidth;
    var height = (float)element.ActualHeight;
    var halfWidth = (float)(width / 2.0);
    var halfHeight = (float)(height / 2.0);

    // Initialize the Compositor
    var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element);

    // Create Scoped batch for animations
    var batch = visual.Compositor.CreateScopedBatch(CompositionBatchTypes.Animation);

    // Rotation animation
    var projectionMatrix = new Matrix4x4(1, 0, 0, 0,
                                            0, 1, 0, 0,
                                            0, 0, 1, 1 / rotationDepth,
                                            0, 0, 0, 1);

    // To ensure that the rotation occurs through the center of the visual rather than the
    // left edge, pre-multiply the rotation matrix with a translation that logically shifts
    // the axis to the point of rotation, then restore the original location
    parent.TransformMatrix = Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, 0) *
                            projectionMatrix *
                            Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(halfWidth, halfHeight, 0);

    // Rotate along the Y-axis
    visual.RotationAxis = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    visual.CenterPoint = new Vector3(halfWidth, halfHeight, 0f);
    visual.RotationAngleInDegrees = 0.0f;

    var rotateAnimation = visual.Compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();

    rotateAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, 90);
    rotateAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, 0);
    rotateAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration);

    visual.StartAnimation("RotationAngleInDegrees", rotateAnimation);

    // Batch is ended an no objects can be added
    batch.End();
}
```

So this code above will rotate along the Y-axis. In the gif below, you'll see that I have it animating on top of another animation which is driven by a PlaneProjection for comparison:

[image]

The "perspective" of both is fine, both in the middle. Now lets change this line of code to switch it for a rotation on the X-axis:

```
// Rotate along the Y-axis
visual.RotationAxis = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
```

Now notice the gif below:

[image]

The composition animation seems to rotate with a perspective that`s more towards the right and not perfectly centered. Does my projection matrix need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a fix, As mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/issues/339#issuecomment-540368398), by simply wrapping the affected control with a container solves the issue :

So in my Xaml I had:

```
<Border Width="300"
        Height="250"
        Background="LightSeaGreen"
        x:Name="Persp"
        Margin="0,0,0,40">
    <TextBlock Text="Composition"
                FontSize="28"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Foreground="White" />
</Border>
```

which I changed to:

```
<Border Width="300"
        Height="250">
    <Border Background="LightSeaGreen"
            x:Name="Persp"
            Margin="0,0,0,40">
        <TextBlock Text="Composition"
                    FontSize="28"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Foreground="White" />
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer.

```
yourVisual.Offset = new Vector3((float)Window.Current.Bounds.Width / 2, (float)Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 2, 0);
```

This will do the trick. Shift visual that has a transformation matrix applied.
Without it, your perspective center is top left corner.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jet Chopper. I added your line of code for the visual, but it remains with a top-left perspective :(

Comment: Thanks for the sample. It's a little complicated and different than my code...I'll try to see if I can get something out of it 

Comment: I can't figure out the fix  :(  I put my code here:

https://github.com/assassin316/Perspective